# React + Enzyme error: Invariant Violation: dangerouslyRenderMarkup(...): Cannot render markup in a worker thread

Tags: reactjs, jsdom, enzyme, server-side-rendering

I am testing a react component using Enzyme and I'm getting the following error:

> Invariant Violation: dangerouslyRenderMarkup(...): Cannot render markup in a worker thread. Make sure `window` and `document` are available globally before requiring React when unit testing or use ReactDOMServer.renderToString for server rendering

I added the following setup for jsdom, before requiring 'enzyme' (as I read in few [places](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/58)):

```
const baseMarkup = '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title></title></head><body></body></html>';
const window = require('jsdom').jsdom(baseMarkup).defaultView;

global.window = window;
global.document = window.document;
global.navigator = window.navigator;

const React = require('react');
const {mount} = require('enzyme');
const sinon = require('sinon');
const SortableInput = require('../../../src/components/sortableInput/sortableInput').default;
```

What am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT**

I don't think it is related to server side rendering. The message is general about unit testing and server side rendering.

Comment: why are you using jsdom with server side rendering?

Comment: I am testing a component that is both rendered on client and server, and I test it with 'mount', which needs 'jsdom'

Comment: `require('jsom')` Is this a typo while pasting into SO?

Comment: @vijayst - yes, sorry - this typo is only here.. thanks (problem still exists)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question, in case someone have the same issue. This was what eventually worked for me:

```
import 'jsdom-global/register';

describe('My awesome component test', () => {
  let cleanup;

  beforeEach(() => cleanup = require('jsdom-global')());

  afterEach(() => cleanup());

  ....
})
```

Answer (score 1):

In one of my project, this is the code to initialise JSDOM, and it is working fine.

```
import { jsdom } from 'jsdom';

before(() => {
  global.document = jsdom('');
  global.window = document.defaultView;
});
```

The before() is a root hook for Mocha. It runs before the beginning of all tests.

Answer (score 0):

One more not so obvious reason for the same error is the `describeWithDOM` method from Enzyme:

```
describeWithDOM('<Slider />', () => {
   describe('render', () => {
     it('should render the slider with one handle by default', () => {
     // and so on
```

According to [enzyme guide](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/guides/jsdom.md) now it is better to avoid this method:

> In previous versions of enzyme, there was a public describeWithDOM API
>   which loaded in a new JSDOM document into the global namespace before
>   every test, ensuring that tests were deterministic and did not have
>   side-effects.
>
> This approach is no longer recommended. React's source code makes
>   several assumptions about the environment it is running in, and one of
>   them is that the global.document that is found at "require time" is
>   going to be the one and only document it ever needs to worry about. As
>   a result, this type of "reloading" ends up causing more pain than it
>   prevents.
>
> It is important, however, to make sure that your tests using the
>   global DOM APIs do not have leaky side-effects which could change the
>   results of other tests. Until there is a better option, this is left
>   to you to ensure.